# ¿Como reconocer un (IF - else) sin llaves?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql

hoy me tope con este script ,soy estudiante de los primeros siglos de DS y al toparme con esto me viene las siguientes preguntas ¿de donde empieza el IF? y ¿don empieza el else? o ¿no tiene else?

```
if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) cn.Close();
cn.Open;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```

Comment: El if solo incluye `cn.Close()` y no hay else.

Comment: entiendo , en otras palabras el primer(;  -punto y coma) es el que termina la sentencia (IF)

Comment: Te recomiendo [*esta lectura*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else), tiene varios ejemplos y te va a ser muy útil leerlos!

Comment: Solo reconocerá hasta el primer punto y coma que se encuentre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si un `if` no tiene llaves, su ámbito se reduce al siguiente comando que se encuentre (en este caso `cn.Close();`).

Para que tenga un `else`, hay que usar la palabra clave `else`, así que en este caso no tiene.

Un ejemplo válido podría ser el siguiente:

```
if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open) cn.Close();
else cn.Open();
```

Yo de todas maneras siempre utilizo las llaves para dejarlo mas claro, y recomiendo que siempre se haga así.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes estas dudas lo primero que recomiendo es que leas la documentacion oficial

[if-else (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else)

Si lo hicieras veras que comenta

> Tanto la `then-statement` como la `else-statement` pueden constar de una única instrucción o de varias instrucciones entre llaves ({}). Para una única instrucción, las llaves son opcionales pero se recomiendan.

Basicamente sino hay llames la instruccion siguiente sera la incluida en la instruccion.